# System of quadratic equations with three variables (generic form)

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

Try solve a system of equation like this one.

\begin{cases} 
(O_x -A_x)^2+(O_y-A_y)^2+(O_z-Az)^2=x^2 \\
(O_x -B_x)^2+(O_y-B_y)^2+(O_z-Bz)^2=y^2 \\
(O_x -C_x)^2+(O_y-C_y)^2+(O_z-Cz)^2=z^2
\end{cases}

Is there any way to express $O_x, O_y, O_z$ in terms of $A_x, A_y, A_z, B_x, B_y, B_z,C_x,C_y,C_z, x, y, z$?

Comment: Are there any constraints on As, Bs, and Cs? Where is this problem coming from?

Comment: x y z can be assumed positive any thing else in the realm of real numbers

Comment: Imagine A B C are known points in 3-D space a forth Point O we know the distance of it between each point and try of work out its 3D coordinate.

Comment: OK. But that means that you assume that the triangle inequality is obeyed for $x$, $y$, $|A-B|$ and so on for the other pairs

Comment: Yes we can assume that if there is going to be any real roots of the solution(and there should be two in mirror position across ABC plane).But the expression should hold even triangle inequality do not meet,you just end up in complex solution.

Comment: This is the intersection of three spheres of given centers and radii. The intersection of two of them is a circle, which meets the third in two points.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a geometric solution. I would use a numerical approach, since writing out a single formula would be ugly.

$A,B,C$ are points that define a plane, and $O$ is a point outside this plane. First, make sure that the corresponding sides obey triangle inequality. I am going to skip this step. 
The lengths of the sides of the tetrahedron are $a=|BC|$, $b=|AC|$, $c=|AB|$, $x=|OA|$, $y=|OB|$, and $z=|OC|$. All these are known.

Then let's calculate the angles between any pair of sides, using generalized Pythagoras' theorem. For example $$\cos\angle OAB=\frac{x^2+c^2-y^2}{2xc}$$
Similarly, $$\cos\angle CAB=\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}$$
Now let's say $P$ is the point on plane $ABC$ where $OP$ perpendicular to $ABC$,$M$ is the point on $AB$ where a plane containing $OPM$ is perpendicular to $AB$. Then $$|AM|=x\cos\angle OAB=\frac{x^2+c^2-y^2}{2c}$$
This allows you to calculate the coordinates of point $M$: $$M_i=\frac{B_i-A_i}{c}|AM|+A_i$$
Now we calculate the lengths of $OM$ and $PM$.
$$|OM|=x\sin\angle OAB=x\sqrt{1-\cos^2\angle OAB}\\|PM|=*********************$$

At this point, you have all lengths in the $\triangle POM$, which allows you to calculate any angles. In particular $$\cos\angle PMO=\frac{|PM|^2+|OM|^2-|OP|^2}{2|PM||OM|}$$

Now let's calculate point $O$. For this, we use the vector product. We know that the $COM$ plane is perpendicular to $AB$ so $\vec{OM}\times\vec{CM}$ is along vector $\vec{AB}$. We also know the magnitude of the cross product, so we write $$\vec{OM}\times\vec{PM}=\pm|OM||PM|\sin\angle PMO\frac{\vec{AB}}{c}$$

All you need is to write the components of the vector product and you have two linear systems in $O_{x,y,z}$, one for each of the signs in the above equation. Writing out explicitly the formula for this terms is tedious, but it's trivial to solve numerically.

Comment: You assuming that there is a plane that perpendicular to AB and also contain O and C at same time which is not true;The plane can contain either O or C but there is no guarantee  it holds both them.You solution give quiet a bit of hint though I might be able to work something out from it.

Comment: Ooops. You are right. Draw the perpendicular from $O$ to $ABC$, say $P$, then perpendiculars from $P$ to $AB$, $AC$, $BC$. Keep calculating lengths and angles, until you get the position of $P$ and the length $|OP|$. Then use the fact that $OP$ is perpendicular to $ABC$ plane

Answer (score 0):

Using algebra, you can do it. I shall assume that there is a solution.

Consider
$$f_1=(O_x -A_x)^2+(O_y-A_y)^2+(O_z-A_z)^2-x^2=0 \tag 1$$
$$f_2=(O_x -B_x)^2+(O_y-B_y)^2+(O_z-B_z)^2-y^2=0 \tag 2$$
$$f_3=(O_x -C_x)^2+(O_y-C_y)^2+(O_z-C_z)^2-z^2=0 \tag 3$$

Develop $f_2-f_1$ and $f_3-f_1$; the are linear equations that you can solve for $O_y$ and $O_z$ as linear functions of $O_x$.

Plug these results in $(1)$; this gives a quadratic equation in $O_x$.

The only problem is that the expressions are really too messy to be reported here.

Comment: In theory yes,in practice no.The result will end up taking pages to write down.I think its part of the question how to write a precise math expression in limited amount of space.

Comment: @shadow_wxh. In practice, it works fine (I made it on paper). You need to define intermediate terms.

Comment: Would you shed some light ...

Comment: @shadow_wxh. I wrote it on paper !

Comment: Ok then it comes to the question how do I steal you paper while being thousands miles away.◔ ‸◔?

Answer (score 0):

We use uppercase letters for vectors and points. WLOG, $C=0$ (otherwise, translate all points by $-C$).

The equations of the spheres are

$$(O-A)^2=a^2,\\(O-B)^2=b^2,\\O^2=c^2.$$

Geometrically, the two solution points are the intersections of the line common to the three planes defined by the pairwise intersections of the spheres (planes of support of circles). This line is orthogonal to the plane $ABC$.

Let the piercing point of the line in $ABC$ be the point $P$. The plane $ABC$ can be described as a linear combination of $CA,CB$, simply written

$$P=\lambda A+\mu B.$$

The two planes of support of the intersection of the spheres $S_A,S_C$ and $S_B,S_C$ are obtained by subtraction of the sphere equations, giving

$$(2P-A)A=c^2-a^2,\\(2P-B)B=c^2-b^2.$$

By substituting the value of $P$, you get

$$2\lambda\,A^2+2\mu\,A\cdot B=A^2+c^2-a^2,
\\2\lambda\,A\cdot B+2\mu\,B^2=B^2+c^2-b^2.$$

This is a $2\times2$ system of equations in $\lambda,\mu$, which allows you to get $P$.

Next, the direction of the line is given by the cross product $$Q:=A\times B$$

and its parametric equation is

$$P+Q\,t$$ which you plug in the equation of the third sphere:

$$(P+Q\,t)^2=Q^2t^2+2P\cdot Q\,t+P^2=c^2.$$

Solve for $t$ and you are done.

Comment: I think you made a mistake replacing O with P (they are not interchangeable) please see the edit.Therefore anything further down is incorrect.

Comment: @shadow_wxh: you misundertood the development. $O=P+Qt$.

Comment: Ok, I get the idea $Qt*A$ is actually $0$.Sorry my vector algebra is a bit rusty.But that is still not what I am asking Basically I am looking for a way to put $O_x$ or $O_y$ or $O_z$ in one side of the equation and everything else on the other side.Any mid term must be linked by equal sign only.It is more about how to dictate a extremely long expression down to a relatively short and comprehensive one.

Comment: @shadow_wxh: my solution is very simple. One $2\times2$ system and one quadratic equation. The complete formula could probably fit on a single line, but that is not necessary IMO.

Comment: the function looks simple the real challenge is when you really get the solution out. I am not familiar with vector functions but I looks the $\lambda \ and \ \mu$ could contain 20~30 terms easily which make P well above a hundred then when it comes to there will be thousands.Could you attempt to actually solve the $\lambda \ \mu \ and \ t$.

Comment: @shadow_wxh: complete nonsense. The whole expression will fit on a single line.

Comment: check my solution below each $DET$ is made of 6 terms if we expand everything that is 43056 terms.You are welcomed to challenge if you can write anything shorter than that but it's ok if you cant be bothered.

Comment: @shadow_wxh: I have no idea what game you are trying to play.

Answer (score 0):

OK lets check this out I'll replace $x \  y \ z$ with $a\ b\ c$ to prevent name collision with function independent variables.

\begin{cases} 
(O_x -A_x)^2+(O_y-A_y)^2+(O_z-A_z)^2=a^2 \ ①\\
(O_x -B_x)^2+(O_y-B_y)^2+(O_z-B_z)^2=b^2 \ ②\\
(O_x -C_x)^2+(O_y-C_y)^2+(O_z-C_z)^2=c^2 \ ③
\end{cases}

$④=①-②$ and $⑤=②-③$ we get

\begin{cases} 
2(A_x-B_x)O_x+2(A_y-B_y)O_y+2(A_z-B_z)O_z-A_x^2-A_y^2-A_z^2+B_x^2+B_y^2+B_z^2+a^2-b^2=0;\ ④ \\
2(B_y-C_y)O_y+2(B_z-C_z)O_z+2(B_x-C_x)O_x-B_y^2-B_z^2-B_x^2+C_y^2+C_z^2+C_x^2+b^2-c^2=0;\ ⑤
\end{cases}

eliminate $O_y$ in $④$ and $O_z$ in $⑤$

\begin{cases} 
O_y=\frac{(B_z-C_z)(A_x^2+A_y^2+A_z^2-a^2)/2+(C_z-A_z)(B_x^2+B_y^2+B_z^2-b^2)/2+(A_z-B_z)(C_x^2+C_y^2+C_z^2-c^2)/2-(A_x(B_z-C_z)+B_x(C_z-A_z)+C_x(A_z-B_z))*O_x}{A_y(B_z-C_z)+B_y(C_z-A_z)+C_y(A_z-B_z)} \\ \\
O_z=\frac{(A_y-B_y)(C_z^2+C_x^2+C_y^2-c^2)/2+(B_y-C_y)(A_z^2+A_x^2+A_y^2-a^2)/2+(C_y-A_y)(B_z^2+B_x^2+B_y^2-b^2)/2-(C_x(A_y-B_y)+A_x*(B_y-C_y)+B_x(C_y-A_y))O_x}{C_z(A_y-B_y)+A_z(B_y-C_y)+B_z(C_y-A_y)}
\end{cases}

name

$A_\sharp =(A_x^2+A_y^2+A_z^2-a^2)/2\quad B_\sharp  =(B_x^2+B_y^2+B_z^2-b^2)/2\quad
C_\sharp  =(C_x^2+C_y^2+C_z^2-c^2)/2\\
DET_{xy}  =\begin{vmatrix}A_x&B_x&C_x\\1&1&1\\A_y& B_y&C_y\end{vmatrix}\quad
DET_{xz}  =\begin{vmatrix}A_x&B_x&C_x\\1&1&1\\A_z& B_z&C_z\end{vmatrix}\quad
DET_{yz}  =\begin{vmatrix}A_y&B_y&C_y\\1&1&1\\A_z& B_z&C_z\end{vmatrix}\\
DET_{\sharp x}  =\begin{vmatrix}A_\sharp&B_\sharp&C_\sharp\\1&1&1\\A_x& B_x&C_x\end{vmatrix}\quad
DET_{\sharp y}  =\begin{vmatrix}A_\sharp&B_\sharp&C_\sharp\\1&1&1\\A_y& B_y&C_y\end{vmatrix}\quad
DET_{\sharp z}  =\begin{vmatrix}A_\sharp&B_\sharp&C_\sharp\\1&1&1\\A_z& B_z&C_z\end{vmatrix}\quad$

$$ \bbox[,border:2px solid red]
{
\begin{aligned}
&\qquad  \text{ An interesting property to notice is}\\
& DET_{xz}DET_{\sharp y}-DET_{xy}DET_{\sharp z}=DET_{yz}DET{\sharp x}\\
&\qquad \quad also \quad DET_{xy}=-DET_{yx}
\end{aligned}
}$$

renaming $O_y$ and $O_z$ to

\begin{cases} 
O_y=\frac{(B_z-C_z)*A_\sharp+(C_z-A_z)*B_\sharp+(A_z-B_z)*C_\sharp+DET_{xz}*O_x}{-DET_{yz}} \\ \\
O_z=\frac{(A_y-B_y)*C_\sharp+(B_y-C_y)*A_\sharp-(C_y-A_y)*B_\sharp+DET_{xy}*O_x}{DET_{yz}}
\end{cases}

and further simplifies to

\begin{cases} 
O_y=\frac{\ DET_{\sharp z}-DET_{xz}*O_x}{DET_{yz}} \quad ⑥\\ 
O_z=\frac{-DET_{\sharp y}+DET_{xy}*O_x}{DET_{yz}} \quad ⑦
\end{cases}

Substitute $O_x$ and $O_y$ into $①$

$O_x^2-2A_xX+A_x^2-a^2
+\bigl[(\frac{DET_{\sharp z}-DET_{xz}O_x}{DET_{yz}})^2-2(\frac{DET_{\sharp z}-DET_{xz}O_x}{DET_{yz}})A_y+A_y^2\bigr]
+\bigl[(\frac{-DET_{\sharp y}+DET_{xy}O_x}{DET_{yz}})^2-2(\frac{-DET_{\sharp y}+DET_{xy}O_x}{DET_{yz}})A_z+A_z^2\bigr]=0$

and further reduce to

$(DET_{xy}^2+DET_{yz}^2+DET_{xz}^2)
-2(DET_{yz}^2A_x+DET_{xz}(DET_{\sharp z}-DET_{yz}Ay)+DET_{xy} (DET_{\sharp y}+DET_{yz}A_z))O_x
+DET_{yz}^2(A_x^2-a^2) +(DET_{\sharp z}-DET_{yz}Ay)^2+(DET_{\sharp y-DET_{yz}Az})^2=0$

then we can solve $O_x$ using "Quadratic formula"
$
Ox=\frac{DET_{yz}^2A_x+DET_{xz}(DET_{\sharp z}-DET_{yz}A_y)+DET_{xy}(DET_{\sharp y}+DET_{yz}A_z)
    \pm \sqrt{
-DET_{yz}^2(DET_{\sharp z}-DET_{yz}A_y)(DET_{\sharp z}-DET_{yz}A_y-2DET_{xz}A_x)  
-DET_{yz}^2(DET_{\sharp y}+DET_{yz}A_z)(DET_{\sharp y}+DET_{yz}A_z-2DET_{xy}A_x) 
-(DET_{xz}(DET_{\sharp y}+DET_{yz}A_z)-DET_{xy}(DET_{\sharp z}-DET_{yz}A_y))^2 
-DET_{yz}^2(DET_{xz}^2+DET_{xy}^2)A_x^2                         
+DET_{yz}^2(DET_{xy}^2+DET_{yz}^2+DET_{xz}^2)a^2}}              
{DET_{xy}^2+DET_{yz}^2+DET_{xz}^2} $

substitude $O_x$ into $⑥\ ⑦$ we get $O_y\ O_z$

or interestingly because $O_x O_y O_z$ are in symmetrical position all you have to do is to swap all $x \leftrightarrow y$ or  $x \leftrightarrow z$ to get O_y and O_z

$
Oy=\frac{DET_{xz}^2A_y+DET_{yz}(DET_{\sharp z}-DET_{xz}A_x)+DET_{yx}(DET_{\sharp x}+DET_{xz}A_z)
    \pm \sqrt{
-DET_{xz}^2(DET_{\sharp z}-DET_{xz}A_x)(DET_{\sharp z}-DET_{xz}A_x-2DET_{yz}A_y)  
-DET_{xz}^2(DET_{\sharp x}+DET_{xz}A_z)(DET_{\sharp x}+DET_{xz}A_z-2DET_{yx}A_y) 
-(DET_{yz}(DET_{\sharp x}+DET_{xz}A_z)-DET_{yx}(DET_{\sharp z}-DET_{xz}A_x))^2 
-DET_{xz}^2(DET_{yz}^2+DET_{yx}^2)A_y^2                         
+DET_{xz}^2(DET_{yx}^2+DET_{xz}^2+DET_{yz}^2)a^2}}              
{DET_{yx}^2+DET_{xz}^2+DET_{yz}^2} $

$
Oz=\frac{DET_{yx}^2A_z+DET_{zx}(DET_{\sharp x}-DET_{yx}A_y)+DET_{zy}(DET_{\sharp y}+DET_{yx}A_x)
    \pm \sqrt{
-DET_{yx}^2(DET_{\sharp x}-DET_{yx}A_y)(DET_{\sharp x}-DET_{yx}A_y-2DET_{zx}A_z)  
-DET_{yx}^2(DET_{\sharp y}+DET_{yx}A_x)(DET_{\sharp y}+DET_{yx}A_x-2DET_{zy}A_z) 
-(DET_{zx}(DET_{\sharp y}+DET_{yx}A_x)-DET_{zy}(DET_{\sharp x}-DET_{yx}A_y))^2 
-DET_{yx}^2(DET_{zx}^2+DET_{zy}^2)A_z^2                         
+DET_{yx}^2(DET_{zy}^2+DET_{yx}^2+DET_{zx}^2)a^2}}              
{DET_{zy}^2+DET_{yx}^2+DET_{zx}^2} $